# Proving that existence of injection $f : S\to \mathbb{N}$ implies $S$ is countable?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How does one formally prove that if there exists an injective function $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ then $S$ is countable? If there exists an injective function $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ then there exists a bijection  $g:S \rightarrow f(S)$ and $f(S)\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is a countable set. But the definition of countable set requires a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $S$? What is missing here?

Comment: First of all $S$ may be finite. Second, if it infinite, use Schröder–Bernstein theorem

Comment: @markvs There is no need to use Shroeder-Bernstein one can come up with a bijection quite easily in the infinite case.

Comment: @Logic: Schröder–Bernstein in this case (one set is countable) is easy enough. You are just suggesting to repeat their proof without mentioning their names.

Comment: @markvs How are you going to show the injection between N and S ?

Comment: Every infinite set contains a copy of $\Bbb N$ basically by the definition of "infinite".

Comment: @markvs the defintion of infinite is not finite, the fact that every infinite set contains a copy of N, does not follow from the defintion , it in fact requires a little bit of the axiom of choice, so its not even provable in ZF!

Comment: Infinite = contains a copy of every finite set.

Comment: @markvs So what? that does not mean that a copy of  N is in every infinite set, in ZF; note that what you state can be proven without choice using induction. It seems you dont belive what i stated in my previous comment, i can give  you reference if you want, also if you want ping me than you should use @ my name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133616/discussion-between-markvs-and-logic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of countable is that a set is countable precisely when there is a bijective map from it to a subset of the natural numbers.  See for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set).

Therefore your question is answered immediately by definition.

The more interesting question, which is what I think you really mean to ask, is to show that any countable set is either finite, or there is a bijective correspondence between it and $\mathbb{N}$.

Suppose we have an injective map $f\colon S\to \mathbb{N}$.  Suppose that $S$ is not finite.  We will construct a bijection $g\colon  \mathbb{N}\to S$.

Firstly we describe an inductive process for picking elements $s_0,s_1,s_2,\cdots\in S$.

We know $f(S)$ is not empty, as $S$ is not finite (hence not empty), and given $s\in S$ we have $f(s)\in f(S)$.  By the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle)   we may pick $x\in f(S)$ minimal in $f(S)$.  As $f$ injective, there is a unique $s_0\in S$ such that $f(s_0)=x$.

Once $s_0,s_1,\cdots,s_{i-1}\in S$ have been selected, we select $s_i\in S$ as follows.  The set: $$X_i=\{x\in f(S)| x>f(s_{i-1})\},$$ is non-empty, as otherwise the image of $f$ would be a finite set, so $S$ would be finite.  By the well-ordering principle we may pick $x\in X_i$ minimal.  As $f$ injective, there is a unique $s_i\in S$ with $f(s_i)=x$.

Now we claim the function $g\colon \mathbb{N}\to S$ mapping $i\mapsto s_i$ is bijective.

Note that by construction, for $i>0$ we have $f(s_i)\in  X_i$ so $f(s_i)> f(s_{i-1})$.  Then by induction on the size of $j-i$, we have if $j>i$ then $f(s_j)>f(s_i)$.  Thus $g$ must be injective.

Now pick an arbitrary $s\in S$.  To show that $g$ is surjective, we must show that $s=s_i$ for some $i\in \mathbb{N}$.  We know $f(s_i)$ is an increasing sequence, so for some $j\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $f(s)<f(s_{j})$, which is minimal in $X_j$, so $f(s)\notin X_j$.

To complete our proof we will prove by induction that for $j>0$:$$f(S)=\{f(s_0),f(s_1),\cdots,f(s_{j-1})\}\cup X_j$$

Thus we have that $f(s)=f(s_i)$ for some $i<j$ and $s=s_i$.

We selected $f(s_0)$ minimal in $f(S)$, so for every element $x\in f(S)$, either $x=f(s_0)$ or $x>f(s_0)$ so $x\in X_1$:$$f(S)=\{f(s_{0})\}\cup X_1$$

For the inductive step, we need only note that we selected $f(s_{i-1})$ minimal in $X_{i-1}$, so any element of $X_{i-1}$ is either $f(s_{i-1})$, or greater than $f(s_{i-1})$, so lies in $X_i$:
$$X_{i-1}=\{f(s_{i-1})\}\cup X_i\qquad\qquad (1)$$
Thus for $i\geq 2$: \begin{eqnarray*}f(S)&=&\{f(s_0),f(s_1),\cdots,f(s_{i-2})\}\cup X_{i-1}\\&=&\{f(s_0),f(s_1),\cdots,f(s_{i-2})\}\cup \{f(s_{i-1})\}\cup X_i\end{eqnarray*}
Here the first equality comes from the inductive hypothesis, and the second equality comes from $(1)$.

Comment: (+1) for writing it all out, my point to markvs is that constructing an injection between N and S is pretty much as hard as constructing the bijection in the infinite case, so there is no need to use the shroeder bernstein theorem. I hope you agree?

Comment: @Logic  It is a similar construction, where you keep picking $s_i$ inductively, but you do not need to worry about surjectivity so you save a bit there.  Once you add all the back and forth of the schroder bernstein theorem I think you are doing more work than the direct approach.  My only hesitation is that someone might find a way of saying that my argument essentially follows schroder bernstein.  I do not see it though.

Comment: Yes that was my point, it seems markvs belivies that its trivial to take out a copy of N from an infinite set, but does not realise that this actually isnt true in ZF and needs (a little) choice!!

Comment: That makes sense.  Whereas in the above approach we do not have to make choices, as we use the original map $f$ to distinguish a minimal element not already picked.